# Access form_tag submitted params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

I've got around 15 parameters being submitted (using tag helpers as no data related to a model). Is there a more efficient way of accessing and maybe storing the params into a hash/array as apposed to having to push all the params into a new array using something like the below:

```
array = []
array << param["a"] 
array << param["b"] 
array << param["c"] 
array << param["d"]
```

etc..

Comment: Probably zillions of ways, but assuming and empty array `arr = []` then `param.each {|k,v| arr << v }` would be one. Check the array API, there's most likely a method that assigns the values of a has to  an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want are the values [then you can do](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
array = hash.values
```

or more specifically to your question:

```
param_array = param.values
```

`values` returns an array of all the values in the hash.